# Collapse duplicate rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has duplicate column names. I want to collapse all the same entries into a single one.

The csv data of the data would be,

```
id,col1,col2,col1,col2
'a',1,0,1,0
'b',0,1,1,0
'c',1,0,0,0
```

The result I am looking for is,

```
id,col1,col2
'a',2,0
'b',1,1
'c',1,0
```

I want to sum over the columns.

I am new to pandas and can't seem to find how to aggregate the values correctly. Note that I have about >4000 columns.

Comment: Is the first row in your desired result a mistake?

Comment: A typo, I corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by column names and aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
print (df.groupby(level= 0, axis=1).sum())
   col1  col2   id
0     2     0  'a'
1     1     1  'b'
2     1     0  'c'
```